# Java : convert long to Timestamp

Tags: java, timestamp, long-integer

I know, how to convert a `Timestamp` to a long, with the [`getTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#getTime--) method.

Is there a method that convert a `long` to a `TimeStamp`?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The constructor is doing that:

```
Timestamp(long time)
```

Answer (score 30):

See: [`Timestamp.Timestamp(long)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#Timestamp%28long%29):

```
new Timestamp(someLong)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's a constructor for Timestamp that takes a long as a parameter.
[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#Timestamp(long)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#Timestamp%28long%29)

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 Timestamp DOES include a constructor with long.
[documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html)

Answer (score -1):

This question is a bit old but for those arriving here scratching their heads because their Timestamp object does not include a `(long)` constructor,
Firebase's [com.google.firebase.Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp) object include `(Date date)` constructor. and `(long seconds, int nanoseconds)`
and [Date](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/java/util/Date.html) does include a `(long)` constructor (which creates a date object based of number of seconds from epoch - same as [java.sql.Timestamp](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/java/sql/Timestamp.html)

bottom line is your solution is simply either

```
Timestamp(new Date(longEpochTimeVar));
```

or

```
Timestamp(longEpochTimeVar,0);
```

0 stands for 0 nanoseconds so both option will produce the same result.

Comment: That's not working. Timestamp(new Date(longEpochTimeVar));