# bgiquery - zeppelin timestamp not rendered as date

Tags: timestamp, google-bigquery

I am running a Bigquery  query on zeppelin using Bigquery interpreter, query is run on a table  having a field whose type is TIMESTAMP.

Behaviour :
1. When the query is executed on google bigquery console, the TIMESTAMP field is seen as date, this is the valid default behavior as it is human readable. Its the same with any SQL database also.
2. When the same query is executed on zeppelin using bigquery interpreter, the TIMESTAMP field is rendered as a LONG type..i.e a huge number.
However  on zeppelin when a query is executed using JDBC interpreter, the TI

We expect Timestamp column to be rendered as date upon doing a select query.

When i added logs in BigQueryInterpreter.java in zeppelin source, field value is printed as long type i.e a big number. So if we want to fix this, what is the right approach because , zeppelin interpreter uses bigquery google api service, i.e google-api-services-bigquery-v2-rev300-1.20.0

> for (TableRow row : response.getRows()) {
>           for (TableCell field : row.getF()) {
>             logger.error("field value : {} ",field.getV().toString());
>             msg.append(field.getV().toString());
>             msg.append(TAB);
>           }

[Timestamp field rendered as number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hc7oH.png)

[SQl, timestamp rendered as date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0JuK.png)

So how can we make sure bigquery returns timstamp as date instead of long type, how can the issue be fixed ?

Comment: This issue only occurs with Zeppelin Interpreter? Why can't you simply reconverted the Long value back to Timestamp after pulling the data?

Answer (score 0):

Since Zeppelin uses Long internally, you can either have their developer add a way to return the data as timestamp or you can convert the data yourself post query.

If it's Java, you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10590324/java-convert-long-to-timestamp).